# Which is not a primitive root?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If p is an odd prime then $6$, $10$ and $15$ cannot all be primitive roots.

My question is this: Why can't all three (simultaneously) be a primitive root modulo $p$?

I have no idea why this is the case. Something is telling me that it's obvious though I don't see it. One observation I have is that each are not mutually relatively prime but all the greatest common divisor of each is 1.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic, which can be used to show that the quadratic character $ X $ satisfies $ X(ab) = X(a)X(b) $. (The quadratic character is a function which returns $ 1 $ when its argument is a quadratic residue, $ 0 $ if its argument is zero and $ -1 $ otherwise.) To do this, note that if you pick a generator $ g $ of the group, then $ X $ is $ 1 $ for elements of even power, and $ -1 $ for elements of odd power. Therefore, the above statement is really saying that two numbers of the same parity have an even sum, and two numbers of distinct parities have odd sums.

**Note:** Mariano Suárez-Alvarez gives a simpler proof without using this fact (that multiplicative groups of finite fields are cyclic) in the comments.

Now, we have the equality mentioned in Hagen von Eitzen's answer, $ 6\cdot 10 = 2^2 \cdot 15 $. If all of these were primitive roots, they would all be non-squares so that we would have 
$$ 1 = (-1)(-1) = X(6)X(10) = X(60) = X(4 \cdot 15) = X(4)X(15) = -1 $$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: One can show that your character $X$ is multiplicative without even having heard about thee fact that the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic.

Comment: Can you sketch a proof?

Comment: Let $Q$ be the set of (non-zero squares) in the multiplicative group $G$. The map $x\in G\mapsto x^2\in Q$ is a surjective homomorphism of groups and (since $p$ is odd) has kernel of order $2$ namely $\{+1,-1\}$. It follows that $Q$ is a subgroup of $G$ of index $2$, and we have a homomorphism $X:G\to G/Q$. As $G/Q$ has two elements, we can identify it with $\{+1,-1\}$. The map $X$ maps elements of $Q$ to $1$ and the other elements, which are not in $Q$, to the other element of its codomain, $-1$.

Comment: Ah, that is a nice proof - thank you for taking the time to type it down.

Answer (score 3):

Primitive roots are non-quadratic residues, as evidenced by Euler's Criterion. But, $$\left(\frac{6}{p}\right) \times \left(\frac{10}{p}\right) \times \left(\frac{15}{p}\right)= \left( \left(\frac{2}{p}\right) \times \left(\frac{3}{p}\right) \times \left(\frac{5 }{p}\right)\right)^2=1$$Which follows from the fact that $6=2 \times 3$, $10=2 \times 5$, $15=3 \times 5$.

Comment: Wow. I knew it was simple. Thank you!

Comment: @user328442 Realize that my proof would have actually been much simpler if I used $6 \times 10 \times 15=30^2$. How unfortunate that I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

In fact they cannot even all be non-squares simultaneously: $6\cdot 10=2^2\cdot 15$.